# How to find out which SCSS files led to a specific CSS setting

Tags: css, sass, google-chrome-devtools, ghost-blog

So I am having this Ghost theme (liebling) that I'd like to modify to my needs. E.g. I'd like to change the font-size of the post title and content.

As the theme is quite complex (at least for me) I am having a hard time to figure out which setting has been made in which SCSS file.

When I start Google Chrome and inspect elements it points me to the CSS file that makes the setting. However it doesn't point me straight to the SCSS file it got created from. Of course it doesn't, as this would require some form of debug-database so chrome is able to deduce/know which SCSS files where involed creating that specific CSS.

So long story short: How can I find out which SCSS file lead to which CSS setting?

Comment: The dirty way is to use `!important` , 
I could try to figure out if you can share the folder structure of sass folder

Comment: Following up on @PrabeshGouli -- I'd even say one of the few _valid_ uses of an `!important` statement is to override some library/framework CSS that you either can't or shouldn't edit directly in the source.

Comment: @PrabeshGouli Thanks for your kind offer. Here is the link to the repository: https://github.com/eddiesigner/liebling

Comment: ok, I will check it out

Comment: If you need to change font-size of post title its on : `liebling/src/sass/components/heading/_title.scss` `line no:21`